# How to use Spring Hateoas with the most decoupling possible

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-hateoas

Basically I want to generate a ReSTful service like I could do with Spring-Data RestRepositories but I need to add a significant amount of domain logic to my services in addition to use two very different data sources. This is a POC. All of the tutorials I have found reference building the links either in the controller when creating the resource or using a resource assembler and pointing to methods. There are very few examples I have found that use entity links, which appears to be a more "decoupled" way of doing this. Furthermore, I have no clear way of generating a landing page at the context root without writing my own controller and just spitting out an instance of resource support (which is fine but I am thinking there is a better way). I know this is a new project, but all of the examples I find are basically copy/paste of each other.

My requirements basically are as such:

1. Have landing page at context root exposing all of my RELs
2. Decouple my resources from the framework's ResourceSupport
3. Decouple the creation of the links from the controllers themselves
4. Apply both collection and singleton patters so that the HAL browser shows the links correctly

I am sure there are some best practices in someone's mind, maybe Oliver's, and I would like to capture those so I can build my POC correctly.

Comment: As an FYI, this is Spring 4 with @RestController, datasources are gem fire and an s3 implementation

Comment: In addition, I have created a demo of the application so to speak on github, https://github.com/fpmoles/spring-hateoas-demo

Comment: "3. Decouple the creation of the links from the controllers themselves" -> IMHO the point of using Spring Hateoas IS to couple controllers and links, so everything is kept consistent without high cost. If you don't want this coupling, then I think adding "manual" links in your DTO is as easy as using Spring Hateoas.